# Filter Radio Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery variable of an array of radio elements.  I want to further select a specific element based on a value.

Below is an idea of what I have but I'm still not sure how to accomplish this.

```js
var gender = 1;
var radiobuttons = $('[name=\'gender\']');  //should contain 2 radio elements
radiobuttons.find('[value=\'' + gender + '\']').prop('checked', true);
```

html

```
<label>Female<input type="radio" name="gender" value="0"></label>
<label>Male<input type="radio" name="gender" value="1"></label>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.find()` method will attempt to select descendant elements. Since an `input` element is self-closed and doesn't contain any descendant elements, nothing is selected.

It seems like you want the [`.filter()` method](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead:

```
var gender = 1;
var radiobuttons = $("[name='gender']");
radiobuttons.filter(function () {
  return this.value === gender.toString();
}).prop('checked', true);
```

or using the [`.is()` method](http://api.jquery.com/is/):

```
radiobuttons.filter(function () {
  return $(this).is("[value='" + gender + "']");
}).prop('checked', true);
```

However, it would be simpler just to use two attribute selectors when initially selecting the elements instead:

```
var gender = 1;
$("[name='gender'][value='" + gender + "']").prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed.  Thanks so much for that.